# Creating barcodes locally in iOS

Tags: iphone

I've been searching all day for a library that makes barcodes, but they're all readers not creators.

I've found a few that (maybe) work.  Jeff LaMarche's works, but for some reason it can't be detected by any readers.  The other ones were very expensive to license and didn't fit my needs.

Does anyone know of a good way to implement barcodes into an iOS app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using a custom barcode font?

There are many types of fonts that you can include in your app.

[image]

Comment: This particular one is `Code 39 Font TrueType` You can download it FREE here: http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/